# Installing 2.77 for LInux

Tags: installation, linux

I just download the 2.77 tarball for Linux but I don't see a way to install the program. I can navigate to the extracted directory and run Blender via ./blender or ./blender-softwaregl but I don't see an install script. Am I missing something?

Comment: You needn't install it. Just run it from where you extracted it. If you want to run it by typing `blender` from anywhere, include the directory in the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't miss anything. The tarball for Linux as well as the zipped version for Windows has no installation routine whatsoever. Extract the archive to whatever directory you like, create a link and you're set. If it runs fine, there are no drawbacks besides of manual updates.

I started using the tarball version years ago after running into downgrades during system updates quite frequently. I always extract it into /home/username/bin/ and also create my link in /home/username/bin/

Alternatively you can use /usr/local/bin/ which would be the correct directory for packages that aren't managed by the system's package manager.

If you want to use an installed version, search the repo of your Linux Distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended using the To install blender from PPA: option found here http://tipsonubuntu.com/2015/04/03/install-blender-2-74-ubuntu-14-04linux-mint-17/
but I will remember you advice and I might just start trying to go that route. I prefer not to add unknowns to my repositories.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes certain packages are just easier to manage outside of the Distribution's repo lists. I use openSUSE and while things got a lot better there, I feel much safer now to have more control over my main working tools.

Comment: @user344658 I'd go with `/usr/local`, as any `bin` should be reserved for actual executables. Coming from multiuser environments, I tend to avoid `/home` for these things. Whether you symlink the blender executable to `/usr/local/bin` or append to the `PATH` variable, as I suggested, is merely a matter of taste.